# Identifying if an answer for velocity is positive or negative

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

So I'm answering this question on use of calculus in applied maths:

If $a= 4s+2$ and initially $s=0$ and $v=1$ m/s, find $v$ when $s=3$.

So far I've done:

$$v\frac{dv}{ds} = 4s + 2$$

which means

$$
\int{v} dv = \int (4s+2) ds
$$

which I've solved to get

$$\frac{v^2}{2} = 2s^2 +2s +C$$

Then I used the information given that when $s=0$, $v=1$ to get $C= \frac{1}{2}$

I've solved $\frac{v^2}{2} = 2s^2 +2s + \frac{1}{2}$ to get $v^2 = 49$.

The answers says the answer is $7$ - what I can't work out is how we know it's +7 and not -7.

Many TIA

Comment: I expect one of them is negative time - that is, before the initial moment. Find $t=\int (1/v)ds$ which comes from $v=ds/dt$

Comment: Velocity is positive and acceleration is positive and in the direction of velocity, so velocity can only increase from $v = 1$

Comment: Please what is $a$ ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion question is about the magnitude of the velocity not about the direction. So your answer should be 7 ( m/s or km/hr what ever). But when you are asked about the direction then you say if it is +7 then it is going towards the positive direction and when -7 it is going backwards.